# Font-Awesome adds attribute aria-hidden which prevents icons from appearing in the browser [SSR]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to include some Font-Awesome Icons in my Next.js project. I've added the needed

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

tag to my Head and then the

```
<i className="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

tag to my render method.
If I open the website in my browser it gives me this console warning:

> index.js:1 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: aria-hidden

and the

```
<i className="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

switches to

```
<i className="fas fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I've already tried the react-fontawesome package but that doesn't seem to work with SSR. Adding

```
aria-hidden="false"
```

manually didn't fix it either.

I guess this is a problem with SSR but I wasn't able to find a good solution or alternative for it.

Comment: Did you try adding the attribute yourself initially?

Comment: Also possibly helpful: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/server-side-rendering

Comment: It is just a warning. Shouldn't really be a problem, right?

Comment: I've tried adding the attribute myself (updated the question).

Comment: It may be a warning, but the icons won't load or show up for me and that's the problem..

Comment: Hi! Did you solve the issue.  I have same issue. it was working before, suddenly i got this error

Comment: Unfortunately not... Looks like there's something wrong when using FontAwesome with NextJS

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and I resolved by adding `aria-hidden` to the icon in this way:

```
<i aria-hidden className="fab fa-whatsapp" />
```

No more warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've had this problem for quite sometime and was never able to solve it until today. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Kirasiris. It is a pleasure being of help :)